# JavaScript time convert

Tags: javascript, timer

I am very new to JavaScript. My guess is that there is a very easy answer.
I need to convert time in the format `hh:mm:ss` to Seconds.

Comment: Do you use any library, or pure JavaScript? there is a possibility that if you use any framework/library then there is such a functionality to convert date/time. You can also take a look at www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var s = "1:01:01";
var a = s.split(":");

var sec = parseInt(a[0], 10)*60*60;
sec += parseInt(a[1], 10)*60;
sec += parseInt(a[2], 10);

alert(sec);
```

Comment: Big gotcha: parseInt may behave in unexpected ways when it is passed an string that contains leading zero: `parseInt("09") -> 0` and `parseInt("010") -> 8`. This is because numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal numbers so for case 1: there is no 9 in octal numbering system and for case 2: octal 10 corresponds to decimal 8. When using parseInt, you must specify radix of 10 for decimal numbers: `parseInt("09", 10) -> 9` and `parseInt("010", 10) -> 10`.

Comment: @Salman Good catch - I always forget about that until I get results that are completely unexpected.  I've edited the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.1"><!--
function split(string,text) {
    splitArray = string.split(text);
    splitIndex = splitArray.length;
}
//--></SCRIPT>


    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
    var splitIndex = 0;
    var splitArray = new Array();

    function calculateTime() {
        splitIndex = 0;
        split(document.myForm.myTime.value,':');

        for (var i=splitIndex-1, j=1, answer=0; i>=0; i=i-1, j=j*60)
            answer += splitArray[i]*j - 0;

        document.myForm.mySeconds.value = answer;
    }
    //--></SCRIPT>

    <FORM NAME="myForm">
    <P>HH:MM:SS = <INPUT NAME="myTime" TYPE="TEXT" MAXLENGTH="8" LENGTH="10">
    <P>Seconds = <INPUT NAME="mySeconds" TYPE="TEXT">
    <P><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" onClick="calculateTime()">
    </FORM>
```